# Hadoop Streaming with Java Mapper/Reducer

Tags: hadoop, jar, hadoop-streaming, wikimedia

I'm trying to run a hadoop streaming job with a java Mapper/Reducer over some wikipedia dumps (in compressed bz2 form). I'm trying to use [WikiHadoop](https://github.com/whym/wikihadoop), which is an interface released by Wikimedia recently.

WikiReader_Mapper.java

> ```
> package courseproj.example;
>
> // Mapper: emits (token, 1) for every article occurrence.
> public class WikiReader_Mapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
>
>     // Reuse objects to save overhead of object creation.
>     private final static Text KEY = new Text();
>     private final static IntWritable VALUE = new IntWritable(1);
>
>     @Override
>     public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> collector, Reporter reporter)
>             throws IOException {
>         KEY.set("article count");
>         collector.collect(KEY, VALUE);
>     }
> }
> ```

WikiReader_Reducer.java

> ```
> package courseproj.example;
>
> //Reducer: sums up all the counts.
> public class WikiReader_Reducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
>
>     private final static IntWritable SUM = new IntWritable();
>
>     public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> collector,
>             Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
>         int sum = 0;
>         while (values.hasNext()) {
>             sum += values.next().get();
>         }
>         SUM.set(sum);
>         collector.collect(key, SUM);
>     }
> }
> ```

The command I'm running is

> ```
> hadoop jar lib/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0.jar \
>        -libjars lib2/wikihadoop-0.2.jar \
>        -D mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=300000000 \
>        -D mapreduce.task.timeout=6000000 \
>        -D org.wikimedia.wikihadoop.previousRevision=false \
>        -input enwiki-latest-pages-articles10.xml-p000925001p001325000.bz2 \
>        -output out \
>        -inputformat org.wikimedia.wikihadoop.StreamWikiDumpInputFormat \
>        -mapper WikiReader_Mapper \
>        -reducer WikiReader_Reducer
> ```

and the error messages I'm getting are

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:157)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:152)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:103)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "WikiReader_Mapper": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
```

I'm more familiar with the new hadoop API vs. old. Since my mapper and reducer code is in two different files, where do I define the JobConf configuration parameters for the job while at the same time, following the command structure of hadoop streaming (explicitly setting the mapper and reducer class). Is there a way I can wrap the mapper and reducer code all up into one class (that extends Configured and implements Tool, which is what's done in the new API) and pass the class name to the hadoop streaming command line vs. setting the the map and reduce classes separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streaming uses the old API (`org.apache.hadoop.mapred`) - yet your mapper and reducer classes extend the new API classes (`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`).

Try changing your mapper to implement `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper`, and reducer to implement `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer`, for example:

```
package courseproj.example;

// Mapper: emits ("article", 1) for every article occurrence.
public class WikiReader_Mapper implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

  // Reuse objects to save overhead of object creation.
  private final static Text KEY = new Text();
  private final static IntWritable VALUE = new IntWritable(1);

  @Override
  public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> collector, Reporter reporter)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    KEY.set("article count");
    collector.collect(KEY, VALUE);
  }
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. Thanks, I didn't know hadoop streaming was only in the old API. I'm still getting an error message related to the JobConf configuration though (post has been updated with new error message).

Comment: hadoop streaming assumes the mapper and reducer arguments are executable files - you've passed java classes. Any reason why you're using hadoop streaming if your map and reduce implementations are written in Java?

Comment: See this page on using Java classes as the mapper / reducer implementations: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/streaming.html#Specifying+a+Java+Class+as+the+Mapper%2FReducer

Comment: basically you need to give the full package path for your mapper / reducer class (`courseproj.example.WikiReader_Mapper`)

Comment: I tried this as well, but with no luck. Still see the same error message about not being able to find the Mapper and Reducer files. Do I need to package the Mapper and Reducer up into separate jars and then add the jars to my HADOOP_CLASSPATH?

Comment: put them in a single jar and add the jar using the `-file myJar.jar` option

Comment: But if we simply implement this interface we need to provide default implementation for a couple of methods. What should that be

Comment: extend `MapReduceBase` and then implement either `Mapper` or `Reducer` - see http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapReduceBase.html

Comment: In the new API, there is a "Context" sent along as parameter, and I use it to get the job name. Is there any way in the old API to get the same information?

Comment: @Mahdi - in your configure method, you can get the job name from the JobConf object passed (JobConf.getJobName())